# Attempting to append an image count for specific image types | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want this function to print the number of ball pictures or the number of firetruck pictures upon user click:

```
function imageCounter (){

var ballCount = 0;
var truckCount = 0;

$('img[src*=ball]').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
        ballCount+=1;
    }     
    $('#radioButtons').append("There are " + ballCount + " ball images.");
 });


$('img[src*=truck]').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
        truckCount+=1;
    }
    $('#radioButtons').append("There are " + truckCount + " truck images.");
    });

}
```

I feel like I'm close..

I have 4 ball images, and 1 firetruck image. My code currently doesn't give me the number value of images, instead it prints out the output message 4 times for the balls, and 1 time for the firetruck.

Any advice on where to go from here?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to move the append message line out of the foreach loops:

```
function imageCounter() {

  var ballCount = 0;
  var truckCount = 0;

  $('img[src*=ball]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      ballCount += 1;
    }
  });

  $('#radioButtons').append("There are " + ballCount + " ball images.");

  $('img[src*=truck]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      truckCount += 1;
    }
  });
  $('#radioButtons').append("There are " + truckCount + " truck images.");
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much it. You could also just print out one message at the very bottom or do something else with the variables again after both loops.

Comment: This works, and now it's not repeating each sentence according to the number of images it has. But it is also just giving me 0 for image count, it's not considering my counter at all :/ Any thoughts as to why?

Answer (score 1):

I notice a couple things. First thing being that `$(this).prop("checked")` will be called on the `<img>` tag, which are not checked unless you are setting them to checked somewhere else in code that's not shown here. (meaning `truckCount` and `ballCount` are not incremented)

Second being the fact that `$('#radioButtons').append(...)` is being called within your each "loop" so to speak so it will be appending that line for every `<img>` tag that matches the selector.

Comment: +1 also something to note, `checked` is not a property for an `img` tag therefore if you added the checked via markup then you need to use the `.attr` to retrieve it unless you set its value with the `.prop` in the JS

Comment: Thank you for this! Made me go back and study what the 'check' was actually doing. Decided to take tha out altogether. and did if($(this).attr('src'))